# "Herrn Miller" as a type of address in a formal letter

Tags: meaning-in-context

So I'm practicing writing formal letters in German. I'm currently learning die höflichen Anreden".

> Herrn Miller. Vielen Dank für Ihrer E-Mail.

Here I'm basically trying to replicate the English "To Mr Miller..." by placing the address in Dative. Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: This is extremely old fashioned. I would say it has become almost obsolete. You would only use it in the address field of a letter not in an email.

Comment: "Anrede" as in you're already talking to him?

Comment: There's another aspect you may want to note: When you omit most or all of the usual honorifics and "niceties", most people will probably assume you're disgruntled or even consider it plainly insulting. Think of starting an English letter with "To Mr Miller" instead of "Dear Mr Miller" or similar.

Comment: apart from everything else, your pronominal declension is wrong, should be "Ihre", not "Ihrer"

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard form of address for formal letters and you should use that and no other:

- Sehr geehrter Herr Miller, …
- Sehr geehrte Frau Schulze, …
- Sehr geehrte Frau Schulze, Sehr geehrter Herr Miller, …
- Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, …
- Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, Sehr geehrter Herr Miller, …

Answer (score 1):

The recipient of a postal item in Germany is determined by **the order of** the details in the address, and this is legally binding (Privacy of Correspondence law):

**Firma F&F**⏎ **Herr Müller**⏎ Street and house number⏎ Zip code and city: This will indicate that the shipment can be opened by anyone in company F&F. It should go to Mr Müller, but if he is not available because he is on vacation, it can also be processed by a colleague who is familiar with the matter.

**Herr Müller**⏎ **Firma F&F**⏎ Street and house number⏎ Postal code and city: This will indicate that the shipment may only be opened personally by Mr. M (first). No one else is allowed to look into it first or process it. If Mr. Müller is on vacation, it must remain unopened for him and may not be processed.

Comment: AFAIK, this is outdated (see e.g. https://openjur.de/u/95106.html) and the order of the business/institution's name and the person's name do *not* matter. If the business is given in the address, it's a business letter and the business can say who should open it: e.g. the mailroom or a vacation replacement. (Exception would be c/o as in "Subcontractor ⏎ c/o Client Business ⏎ address" - but I wouldn't rely too much on that) If you want something to be opened by the specified person and noone else, mark it as *persönlich* (in person) or *vertraulich* (confidential) or both.

Comment: Possibly a bit counterintuitively, z.Hd. = zu Händen (to the hands of) is only a hint to speed up internal routing, and again e.g. a vacation replacement is supposed to open such items. z.Hd. is followed by genitive, btw, so Herrn: "z. Hd. Hrn. Miller"

Answer (score 0):

Omitting the preposition "an" can work if the e-mail you answer to ended with the question *"Who do you want to write to?"*, and even then it would be colloquial in my opinion, as in written form, full sentences are preferred.
You should include the preposition and write "An Herrn Miller".